# Onclick not working in kendo MVC Grid's Client Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have following code in my Razor View. Grid displays link but Onclick event doesn't fire. What should i do to make sure it's wired properly with the event handler

```
columns.Template(c => c).ClientTemplate("# if (IsVerified == true) { #" +
                                                                  "<text><a  onclick=\"show('#=data#') href='\\#'\">View</a></text>" +
                                                                  "# } else if(IsVerified == false) { #" +
                                                                  "<text><a onclick=\"verify('#=data#') href='\\#'\">Verify</a></text>" +
                                                                  "# } #").Title("Action").Width("50px").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "text-align:center"});
```

One of the Event handler is as following

```
function show(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var model = grid.dataItem($(event.target).closest("tr"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change from

```
var model = grid.dataItem($(event.target).closest("tr"));
```

to

```
var model = grid.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
```

because pass e not event

Comment: How that would help? Client template dynamically add <a> and onclick event not binding properly. When link clicked , it's not calling event handler